# Is it possible to have "no active cell" in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel VBA “Unselect” wanted](https://superuser.com/questions/469720/excel-vba-unselect-wanted)

Is there a way to **save** a workbook in a state such that when the file is **reopened** no cell is active (in any of its worksheets)?

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not meant for "useless ... trivia questions".  That said, I do see some use for the latter part of your question.  More particularly:  Is there a way to set a "default view" for a workbook, that is independent of the last "active cell" at the time it was saved?  I do find it annoying to open a workbook and find it already pointing to some odd location or sheet, or having some weird filter, that the person working on it previously had just used.

Comment: There.  Hopefully, that edit helps.

Comment: The question title and the question text have absolutely nothing to do with one another at this point in time. The question title is about "no active cell"; the text is about setting the active cell to a sane default like the first sheet's A1 cell. I don't think either question is trivial or useless, and I don't think we should have edited the OP's question into something other than what was originally asked. However, both questions deserve a legitimate answer.

Comment: @allquixotic Did you read the original question?  The title may be a bit more separated from the text now, but the intent of the question remains the same.  The original question was just poorly formed.  (Title now fixed, too.)

Comment: @Iszi: I originally described my question as "useless trivia" in the hopes to forestall comments and answers that want to know why I want to do what I'm asking about (I happen to find such questions infuriating beyond words).  I now see that this idea backfired big time...

Comment: @kjo Would you agree that my edit effectively expresses what you're looking for, or are you trying to fix a different problem?  If the latter is true, I apologize - please feel free to re-edit.

Comment: @kjo Such comments are often justified, due to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/194308) (people asking about their attempted solution, rather than the actual problem they're trying to solve). While classifying your question as "useless trivia" might avoid such questions, it'll raise others, namely about the suitability of such a question for this site. After all, the goal here is to have *useful* questions.

Comment: The original post seemed to be a duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/q/469720/76571

Comment: @Excellll Very close, though this is referring to manual user interaction where the proposed duplicate is asking about scripting.  Not sure how much of a difference that will make since your proposed duplicate doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Indrek: I'm well aware of the "XY problem" meme, but ***as a matter of principle*** I choose to treat the asker as an adult who knows what he/she wants, and who is perfectly capable, if the situation warrants, of adding to the question remarks like "I'm not sure if this is the right way to solve problem X, feel free to suggest a better approach", etc.  Absent such an invitation, attempts to tell me what I "really should be asking" is just condescending and insulting.  (BTW, I'm perfectly aware that most of the world sees these matters differently, no need to remind me of it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no way to stop selection from occurring. Excel requires the cursor to be positioned somewhere.

The best you can do is to protect the worksheet, and uncheck every item. Selection is still possible, by typing the address directly, but mouse clicks will not work. If you put the cursor in a hidden row and column, it will not be immediately obvious where the cursor actually is